# How to pass String variable inside the html tag in swift?

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode

Now Trying to pass src as string variable but it's not working.

```
func SearchCall() {

    let embedCode = "<iframe width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" src=\"("\(self.searchUrl)")\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"

    webView.loadHTMLString(embedCode, baseURL: nil)


}
```

Comment: Seems like it's just a syntax error. `src=\"\(searchUrl)\"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
 let searchUrl = "URL"
 let embedCode = "<iframe width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" src=\"\(searchUrl)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
 print(embedCode)
 webView.loadHTMLString(embedCode, baseURL: nil)
```